# Tableau highlight/tree map hybrid

Tags: tableau-api, treemap

I am new at Tableau and have been trying to create a visualization from a simple spreadsheet with hierarchical levels and a count.  I can get the correct structure from a highlight table, but would like to have the color distribution of a treemap.

So here is the spreadsheet - 4 levels, a label (at leaf level), a count and a code.  The desired output is (I mocked it up in Excel) is next to it: [example data and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Vao.jpg)

I have been able to create a highlight table (which is almost right but misses the color highlighting of the levels) and a treemap (but the data is not represented with a hierarchical left to right model I am looking for.  [Attempt in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFOrQ.jpg).

At first I thougth this would be easy, but have spent a couple of evenings on it unsuccessfully.  Ay help would be appreciated.  Thanks,  John

Comment: Your example is very clear. I have a hard time telling what you want to do. Can you simplify or clarify?

Comment: Hi Alex - I am not sure how to further clarify - but basically I am after a color coded hierarchy based on a measure  at the 'leaf' level of the branches.  So imagine the example data link above as a set of trees with the trunk to the left.  The measure at the leaf  level is color coded and what I am after is a cascading color travelling from the leaf to the trunk.  Hope this helps.

Comment: When it gets tricky, I suggest separating the issue of calculating a value from displaying it - solving them as individual puzzles - maybe on simplified data. Then put the pieces back together. So I would start by making a simple text table with a number showing the intensity you want to eventually drive the color or size of each cell. You'll likely need table and/or LOD calcs. Separately you can experiment with how to create the viz based on a value (perhaps dummied up while you are working on getting the calc right)